# useState Hooks not working with enzyme mount()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

The `setWishlists` hook in this component seems to not run, even though everything before and after it in the promise chain runs. It just doesn't change `wishlists`. In my test's setup: `handleGetWishlists` is passed through a jest mock so that it can still be used in the component while allowing jest to spy on it. The implementation is still passed through so that [Mock Service Worker](https://mswjs.io/) an provide the data instead of mocking fetch.

My repo on the relevant branch is [here](https://github.com/thirionlogan/amazonia/tree/home-page/src/components/HomePage)

Relevant section:

```js
//HomePage.js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {
  Accordion,
  AccordionSummary,
  AccordionDetails,
  Typography,
  FormGroup,
  FormControlLabel,
  Checkbox,
} from '@material-ui/core/';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  homeContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  heading: {},
  accordion: {
    width: '50%',
  },
}));

const HomePage = ({ handleGetWishlists }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [wishlists, setWishlists] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    handleGetWishlists()
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('DATA BEFORE SET', data); //--> DATA BEFORE SET [...somedata...]
        return data;
      })
      .then(setWishlists) // --> console.error()
      .then(() => console.log('WISHLIST AFTER SET', wishlists)); // --> WISHLIST AFTER SET []
    console.log('END OF USE EFFECT');
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={classes.homeContainer}>
      {wishlists.map((wishlist, index) => {
        return (
          <Accordion key={`Accordian${index}`} className={classes.accordion}>
            <AccordionSummary
              expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
              aria-controls='panel1a-content'
              id='panel1a-header'
            >
              <Typography className={classes.heading}>
                {`${wishlist.name} by ${wishlist.author}`}
              </Typography>
            </AccordionSummary>
            <AccordionDetails>
              <FormGroup>
                {wishlist.items.map((item, index) => {
                  return (
                    <FormControlLabel
                      key={`WishlistItemCheckbox${index}`}
                      control={<Checkbox />}
                      label={item.name}
                    />
                  );
                })}
              </FormGroup>
            </AccordionDetails>
          </Accordion>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

```js
//HomePage.test.js
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { handleGetWishlists } from '../../client/client';
import HomePage from './HomePage';
import { Accordion } from '@material-ui/core/';

describe('HomePage', () => {
  let component;

  const mockHandleGetWishlists = jest.fn();

  beforeEach(async () => {
    mockHandleGetWishlists.mockImplementation(handleGetWishlists);
    component = mount(<HomePage handleGetWishlists={mockHandleGetWishlists} />);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    mockHandleGetWishlists.mockReset();
  });

  it('should load wishlists', async () => {
    expect(mockHandleGetWishlists).toBeCalled();
    mockHandleGetWishlists()
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(console.log);
    expect(component.exists(Accordion)).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

```js
//client.jsconst
client = {
  //...
  handleGetWishlists: () =>
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/wishlist', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    }),
  //...
};

module.exports = client;
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `wishlists` will contain the updated value only in the **next run** of `useEffect()`, not yet in the same run, so `console.log('WISHLIST AFTER SET', wishlists)` still shows the old value.

Your `useEffect` is (intentionally) only called once, so you can not console.log the updated wishlist inside the useEffect. You just never have it there.

However, I would expect your `wishlists.map()` should correctly use the updated `wishlists`, assuming that the `data` returned from `handleGetWishlists()` is correct.

If you want to console.log the updated `wishlists`, you need to use a **2nd** `useEffect()`, like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log( 'WISHLIST AFTER SET', wishlists );
}, [ wishlists ]);
```

Comment: I have refactored my code and `wishlists` evaluates to an empty array in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

When `setWishlist` is used as a callback in the promise chain, its context changes from your react component state to that of the Promise itself. Calling `setWishlist` directly from the handler should set `wishlist` as expected.

```
handleGetWishlists()
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('DATA BEFORE SET', data); //--> DATA BEFORE SET [...somedata...]
        setWishlist(data);
      })
```

Comment: if I use `useEffect(() => {console.log('WISHLISTS', wishlists)}, [wishlists]);` to see when `wishlists` is changed, it looks like with both implementations, it does 'change', however it seems to change from `[ ]` (an empty array) to `[ ]` (an empty array)